# Why does X value and X value not correspond?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a contribution to an open source project on GitHub right now, and I'm absolutely confused by this one particular issue.

The issue is that the footer, which has a `fixed` position, obscures some of the content once there is enough content.

I assumed fixing this issue would be as easy as applying a given value to the `height` of `footer`, and then using that same value for the `margin-bottom` of `main`, which is the container that holds the content. For instance...

```
main   { margin-bottom : 3vh }
footer { height        : 3vh }
```

But -- for whatever reason -- the values never seem to properly correspond.

**What the hell is going on?**

```css
/* Friends of Girl Develop It Columbus styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
    background: black;
}

main {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    
    opacity: 0.5; /* for testing */
    height: 3vh;
}

footer a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Friends of Girl Develop It Columbus!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="images/gdic.jpeg" width="180" height="180" alt="GDIC" >
    </header>
    <main>

      <h1>Friends of Girl Develop It Columbus</h1>
      <!-- Copy the template below, paste it below the last person's entry, and add your information!

        <li class="friend">
          <strong class="name">Replace this text with your name!</strong> is on
          <a class="github-repo" href="REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_GITHUB_PROFILE_URL">GitHub</a>
        </li>

      -->

      <h2>In no particular order!</h2>

      <ul class="friends">
        <li class="friend">
            <strong class="name">Caitlin</strong> is on
            <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/csteinert">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Parker</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/parkerdyer" title="Parker's GitHub">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Melissa</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Anthony</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/gtkpr">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        
        
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">1</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">2</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">3</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">4</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">5</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">6</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">7</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">8</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">9</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">10</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">11</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">12</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">13</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">14</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">15</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">16</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">17</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">18</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">19</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">20</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">21</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">22</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">23</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">24</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">25</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">26</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">27</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">28</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">29</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">30</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">31</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">32</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">33</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">34</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">35</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">36</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">37</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">38</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">39</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">40</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">41</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">42</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">43</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">44</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">45</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">46</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">47</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">48</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">49</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">50</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        
        
      </ul>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <a href="https://github.com/csteinert/friends-of-gdic">View repository</a>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

At first I thought it was because the font was preventing the footer from shrinking, but this actually has nothing to do with it.

I have attached a demo of another solution (which doesn't works but doesn't) I had come up with below, which also starts to bug out if you adjust the values of `--footer-height`.

```css
/* Friends of Girl Develop It Columbus styles */

/*************************************************** newly added */
:root {                  /*                                      */
  --footer-height: 40px; /* value can be adjusted to your liking */
}                        /*                                      */
/*****************************************************************/

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background: black;
}

main {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /************************************************* newly added */
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--footer-height) * 1); /*              */
  /*                                                             */
  /* you can increase the multiplier to create makeshift padding */
  /* or margin.                                                  */
  /*                                                             */
  /***************************************************************/
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
    /*********************************************** newly added */
    height: var(--footer-height); /*                             */
    /*************************************************************/
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    
opacity:0.5;
}

footer a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <img src="images/gdic.jpeg" width="180" height="180" alt="GDIC" >
    </header>
    <main>

      <h1>Friends of Girl Develop It Columbus</h1>
      <!-- Copy the template below, paste it below the last person's entry, and add your information!

        <li class="friend">
          <strong class="name">Replace this text with your name!</strong> is on
          <a class="github-repo" href="REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_GITHUB_PROFILE_URL">GitHub</a>
        </li>

      -->

      <h2>In no particular order!</h2>

      <ul class="friends">
        <li class="friend">
            <strong class="name">Caitlin</strong> is on
            <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/csteinert">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Parker</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/parkerdyer" title="Parker's GitHub">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Melissa</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">Anthony</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/gtkpr">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        
        
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">1</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">2</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">3</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">4</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">5</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">6</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">7</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">8</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">9</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">10</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">11</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">12</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">13</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">14</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">15</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">16</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">17</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">18</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">19</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">20</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">21</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">22</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">23</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">24</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">25</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">26</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">27</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">28</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">29</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">30</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">31</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">32</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">33</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">34</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">35</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">36</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">37</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">38</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">39</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">40</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">41</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">42</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">43</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">44</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">45</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">46</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">47</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">48</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">49</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li class="friend">
           <strong class="name">50</strong> is on
           <a class="github-repo" href="https://github.com/melissa3000">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        
        
      </ul>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <a href="https://github.com/csteinert/friends-of-gdic">View repository</a>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the data can't fit into the required height you set it will have to overflow somewhere...

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum the data fits fine. the height automatically adjusts. you can test this by giving `main` a border. i've edited my question to hopefully add to its clarity

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the whole question :)

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum if you understand the HTML/CSS, you'd know that the height of `main` will automatically adjust to contain all of the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer has a 10px padding. Consider removing *padding* or use `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: wow. i didn't know border-box effected the padding too. thanks <3